# Android app’s limitations on accessibility when running in background

Tags: android

What are the limitations of an android app while running in background on accessibility control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Yes, it can.**

Yet, however you'll need to run a `Service` (for background app) and your app must have all the required permissions for the actions you've listed. To change volume, you may look into `AudioManager`.

Your app can access public data of other apps by initiating `ContentResolver` which will access `ContentProvider` component of apps (s.a. notes, contacts or reminders). Your app, indeed, can get current location with `LocationServices` API.